# RoR: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error in my rails view:

```
app/views/welcome/index.html.haml:55: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')' ...ut.attributes({}, nil, :value="#{num}")}>#{_hamlout.adjust_t... ... ^
```

Here is the two lines that cause it (54 and 55 respectively)

```
=(1..52).each do |num|
      %option{:value="#{num}"} #{num.to_s} weeks
```

I am bassically just trying to connect "number " with "weeks" with the `+` string operator. 
But i am clearly in the wrong on my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing > on second line. Try this:

```
=(1..52).each do |num|
     %option{:value => "#{num}"}
```