# Why is "true || File.exist? 'touch'" invalid syntax?

Tags: ruby, syntax, syntax-error

The following is invalid:

```
true || File.exist? 'touch'
SyntaxError: unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting end-of-input
true || File.exist? 'touch'
                     ^
```

However, if you remove the `true ||`, or use brackets around `'touch'`, it's valid:

```
File.exist? 'touch'
=> false

true || File.exist?('touch')
=> true
```

Why is the combination of the `true ||` and not using brackets invalid syntax?

Doing a search for `SyntaxError: unexpected tSYMBEG` only got https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/1232 , and doing a search for `SyntaxError: unexpected tSTRING_BEG` seemed to mainly get people who'd made some sort of typo such as [RoR: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818235/ror-syntax-error-unexpected-tstring-beg-expecting) and [Ruby syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ':' (SyntaxError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778107/ruby-syntax-error-unexpected-tstring-beg-expecting-syntaxerror)

Comment: Parentheses in Ruby is optional. But it becomes necessary in ambiguous cases like this. Here Ruby parser gets confused what is the part of which.

Comment: What's the point of "prefixing" an expression with `true ||`?

Comment: @Stefan in my case, it was to avoid `File.exist?('touch')` (or its real-life equivalent) from being run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work

```
true or File.exist? 'touch'
```

The reason is does is because `||` has higher precedence than `or`, and with `||` your expression simplifies to `(true || File.exist?) 'touch'`.

I'm not recommending you use `or`, but consider always using parenthesis - most Ruby guidelines (Vanilla Ruby and Rails) recommend using them at all times.

[Community driven ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide):

> Omit parentheses around parameters for methods that are part of an internal DSL (e.g. Rake, Rails, RSpec), methods that have "keyword" status in Ruby (e.g. attr_reader, puts) and attribute access methods. **Use parentheses around the arguments of all other method invocations.**